# MS Access "does not recognise ... as a valid field name"

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
TRANSFORM Count(Breakdown.Hours) AS CountOfHours
SELECT Breakdown.Description, Breakdown.Customer, Count(Breakdown.Hours) AS [Total Of Hours]
FROM Breakdown
WHERE Breakdown.Code = [Forms]![Pre-Break]![Code]
GROUP BY Breakdown.Description, Breakdown.Customer
PIVOT Breakdown.Day;
```

This is the SQL statement I am tring to run, I have a combo box in Pre-Break form form called Code , This syntax has worked with other SQL statements for me where I haven't had GROUP BY and PIVOT after the WHERE. I have tried putting the after at the end but I still get an error. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly declaring the form-value as a parameter - made a difference when I tried to run this:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![Pre-Break]![Code] Text (255);
TRANSFORM Count(Breakdown.Hours) AS CountOfHours
SELECT Breakdown.Description, Breakdown.Customer, Count(Breakdown.Hours) AS [Total Of Hours]
FROM Breakdown
WHERE Breakdown.Code = [Forms]![Pre-Break]![Code]
GROUP BY Breakdown.Description, Breakdown.Customer
PIVOT Breakdown.Day;
```

If the Code is an integer then use `Short` instead of `Text(255)`.

Comment: I have a form which opens this query, When I select the code in the form and open the query it works fine, but when I change the number in the form and try reopen the query it just stays on the previously opened numbers any idea ?

Comment: If you haven't closed the query then it will be activated rather than running again. Close the query each time, otherwise you'll need to write some code that will: find it, close it and open it again.

Comment: Iv tried opening and closing it and it still dosent change to the number selected !? :(